# Partial duplicate detection in Excel

Tags: excel

I have customer file in Excel (using 2003) with about 16000 rows. The columns are name, phone, email etc. Some of the customers work for the same company, and I need to create a second spread sheet that lists each company with multiple contacts and those contacts. I thought a great way to do this would be to find a formula that would look at each email address and highlight duplicate email domains. Basically what ever is after the @. If each duplicate was high lighted, I could go in a CTRL+F each email domain to identify the duplicates. Is this possible to do in Excel?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your emails are in (e.g.) Column D, you could insert a column to the right, add this in E2 and fill down

```
=MID(D2, SEARCH("@",D2)+1,50)
```

Comment: AWESOME. Now all I need to do is find duplicates on E?